# Cypress click is not scrolling into view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, cypress

There is site built in *Vue/Nuxt* and has *SSR* and has links in the footer.

Making test the link is found, link is visible and `click()` says that *link is not in the view*.

After the click failing the link is scrolled to the view.

What can cause the view not to be scrolled into the view?

```
        it('About us page', () => {
            cy.visit('https://test.fooddocs.ee');
            cy.url().should('include', 'https://test.fooddocs.ee');
            cy.get('footer.page-footer').within(() => {
                cy.get('a')
                    .contains('About us')
                    .should('be.visible')
                    .should('have.attr', 'href', '/about')
                    .click();
            });
            cy.url().should('include', siteUrl + '/about');
            cy.get('main h1').should('contain', 'Our team');
        });
```

[image: Test screenshot]

Comment: This error means that the element is in the DOM, but is currently being covered by something else.

Comment: You can try `cy.scrollTo` to scroll to the footer and also try `.click({force: true})` https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollto.html#Syntax

Answer (score 3):

1. `Click` method is kind of imitation of behavior of the app user. My proposition is to try with `trigger(click)` which is little different - I believe in this case `trigger(click)` refers to **Element Click** which is handled by the **DOM Element**. - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger.html#Syntax
2. Another solution I can think off may be kind of workaround but eventually will be helpful - try to set another position on `click()` than `center`, because Cypress by default set position to always click on the center of the element you want to interact with. For example `click(left)` - check Cypress documentation - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click.html#Arguments

Answer (score 1):

The error message in your screenshot "center of this element is hidden" indicates that cypress is able to find the element but failed perform the "click". The {force:true} or .scrollTo('bottom') may not actually do any better. One alternative for the test would be to mimic the click by visiting the underlying url. If intention is to test it by a 'click' then need more investigation why the element's center is not in view. Please read below.

```
.should('have.attr', 'href', '/about')
            //.click();
            .invoke('attr','href')
                .then((url)=>{
                    cy.visit(siteUrl + url);
                });
```

[image]

I think {force:true} appear to work, but is not essentially completing the task hence the url still not redirected (nor the page reloaded) as desired. see below, the test failed.

[image]

Also, the scroll to bottom appear to succeed but we only notice the page scroll after the fact the test has already been failed. See below.

[image]